# Transforming ciphertext from digital format to alphabetic format

Tags: encoding, language-agnostic, character-encoding, cryptography

Consider a message "STOP" which we are to encrypt using the RSA algorithm. The values given are p = 43, q = 59, n = pq, e = 13. At first I have transformed "STOP" into blocks of 4-bit code which are 1819 (S = 18 and T = 19) and 1415 (O = 14, P = 15) respectively (alphabets are numbered from 00 to 25).

Finally after calculation I have got 20812182 as the encrypted message (after combining 2081 and 2182). Is there any way to transform this digital code of the ciphertext to the alphabet form?

If we start by considering 2 bits, then 20 = U, 81 = ?, 21 = V, 82 = ?,what will be the alphabets for 81 and 82? I mean to ask,what will be the ciphertext for the plaintext "STOP" in the above case?

Comment: You've still got a lot of question left open. If you think you require more input, then please indicate this, especially if someone explicitly asks you if anything is missing from their answer. Otherwise, please try and accept questions once they are answered.

Answer (score 0):

RSA works with numbers not binary data nor letters. You can of course convert one to another. E.g. this is what you did when you wrote `20812182`. The number with that value can have an endless number of other *representations*.

Now creating an alphabetical representation that has a minimum size is pretty tricky to do. Basically you can divide by powers of 26. This is however not easy to implement. Instead you can take a subset of your alphabet and use that to represent your number.

To do this use your original number representation and replace `0` with `A`, `1` with `B` ... and `9` with `J`. This would result in `CAIBCBIC` for your ciphertext.

Note that plaintext and ciphertext are used as names for the input and output of cryptographic ciphers. Both names seem to indicate some kind of human readable text - and maybe they once did - but in cryptography they can be thought of as any kind of data.

Comment: Anything you do not understand from my answer, C_beginner?